# Converting PyTorch transforms.compose method into Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I understand that we use transforms.compose to transform images via torch.transforms. I want to do the same in Keras  and spending hours on internet I couldnt get how to write a method in keras that can do the same. Below is the Torch way:

```
# preprocessing
data_transform = transforms.Compose([
   transforms.ToTensor(),
   transforms.Normalize(mean=[.5], std=[.5])
])
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit trivial in Tensorflow. Tensorflow recommends using the pre-processing/augmentation as part of the model itself.

I do not have your complete code but I assume you would be using `tf.data.Dataset` API to create your dataset. This is the recommended way of building the dataset in Tensorflow.

Having said that you can just prepend augmentation layers in your model.

```
# Following is the pre-processing pipeline for e.g
# Step 1: Image resizing.
# Step 2: Image rescaling.
# Step 3: Image normalization

# Having Data Augmentation as part of the input pipeline.
# Step 1: Random flip.
# Step 2: Random Rotate.

pre_processing_pipeline = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Normalization(mean=[.5], variance=[.5]),
])

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
])

# Then add it to your model.
# This would be different in your case as you might be using a pre-trained model.

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  # Add the preprocessing layers you created earlier.
  resize_and_rescale,
  data_augmentation,
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  # Rest of your model.
])
```

For a complete list of layers check out this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers). The above-given code can be found on the website [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).

Comment: Once data_set is achieved a dataloader is used in torch i.e. data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True). Can you guide me what to use here in Keras?